# How to alter country dropdown in location module?

Tags: hooks, location, users

I have been researching a way to limit the available countries in the drop-down that comes with the contributed locations module. I think `hook_form_alter()` is the way to handle just showing certain countries, but starting a `hook_form_alter()` snippet from hand is not something that I have the ability to achieve. After much googling I have not been able to find a code snippet to get me started.

A project I am working on now only allows registrations from the US and Canada, so I want to limit that drop-down to just those 2 countries. The function that calls the country list is `location_get_iso3166_list()` and the array is `$countries`. The location module is being used to populate pieces in the Content Profile module.

I have found a couple posts online that suggest just commenting out the countries that are not needed in the .inc file; this is not an option for this project as we are on a multi-site set-up, so changing it in the module will affect other sites. I think I need to add a `hook_form_alter()` snippet to the template.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) is a good start.  If you are looking to alter a content type form (and the CCK Location field), one method I have used is to create a really small and simple custom module implementing [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6).  Details/instructions on creating this module can be found below (for Drupal 6, should be similar if not the same for 7).

As an example, I am calling this module 'custom_countries', if you want to change the name, you can always rename the files and do a search and replace in them later.

First you need to create a new folder in your modules folder (`sites/all/modules`, etc).  (All files created from now on should be placed in this folder). Next, create a new file called `custom_countries.info` and put the following inside and save:

```
name = "Custom Countries"
description = "Changes the list of countries available from Location module for certain content types"
core = 6.x
```

Next, create another file called `custom_countries.module`, place the following code inside and save the file:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file custom_countries.module
 * Module to change the countries options of location module
 * for certain content type(s)
 */

/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter()
 */
function custom_countries_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Replace "YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE with the name of the content type desired
  if ($form_id == 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_node_form') {
    $form['#after_build'][] = 'custom_countries_after_build';
  }
}

/**
 * Make changes to countries field after all fields are rendered
 */
function custom_countries_after_build($form_element, &$form_state) {
  // Replace FIELD_NAME with the machine name of the location field for your content type
  $form_element[FIELD_NAME][0]['country']['#options'] = array(
    'ca' => 'Canada',
    'us' => 'United States',
  );
  return $form_element;
}
```

**Important:** be sure to read the comments and change 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE' to the machine name of the content type your location field is in (possibly just 'profile' if using default content_profile settings).  Also, change 'FIELD_NAME' to the machine name of the location field.

Finally, enable the module at `admin/build/modules`.

Now when you are creating/editing the content type you specified, you will only see 2 options in the countries list.  Using this method, you can now easily make changes to other forms as well.

The idea for this came from [Make Location form fields available to hook_form_alter()](http://drupal.org/node/378622#comment-3569390).  If in the future you decide to add other countries, the complete list of key/value pairs can be found at http://api.lullabot.com/location_get_iso3166_list/5

Comment: Unless you still use CVS to manage your code (I hope not!), you do not need the lines with $Id$ anymore :)

Comment: Ah yep, old habit! Edited:)

Comment: thanks much fellas...the code and instructions above were perfect.